# Most efficient way to subset a file by a list of text patterns to match

Tags: bash, grep, match

I have a large, tab delimited file (technically a VCF of genetic variants), call it `file.vcf`, with millions of lines that look something like this

```
locus1    1    15    0    0/0,21,2,2,;0
locus1    2    17    0    0/0,21,2,1,;0
locus2    1    10    0    0/1,21,2,2,;0
locus3    1    2     0    0/1,21,2,1,;0
...
locus123929    1    3    0    1/0,22,2,1,;0
locus123929    2    4    0    1/2,1,1,3,;0
```

I'd like to subset this original file to include all lines from loci in another file (`search-file.txt`). For example, if `search-file.txt` were:

```
locus1
locus3
locus123929
```

Then the final would be:

```
locus1    1    15    0    0/0,21,2,2,;0
locus1    2    17    0    0/0,21,2,1,;0
locus3    1    2     0    0/1,21,2,1,;0
locus123929    1    3    0    1/0,22,2,1,;0
locus123929    2    4    0    1/2,1,1,3,;0
```

What is the most efficient way to subset this large of a file using either bash or R? (Note, reading the entire file into memory, as in R is very very very slow, and often crashes the system.)

Comment: A simple grep would do where you match full words `grep -wFf  pattern.txt file.vcs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `awk`:

```
awk -F'\t' '
    NR == FNR { a[$0]; next }
    $1 in a
' search-file.txt file.vcf > filtered_file
```

`bash` would be too slow for this job.

Note: Make sure the file `search-file.txt` doesn't have DOS line endings.

Alternatively,

```
LC_ALL=C sort search-file.txt file.vcf |
awk '
    NF == 1 { loc = $1; next }
    $1 == loc
' > filtered_file
```

but this version may disturb the original order of lines.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post to be more clear. The loci that I want to search for are in another file, the list is many thousands of loci long. Would awk still be best?

Comment: @AlexKrohn I believe `awk` would be still best as long as the array resulting from reading the `search-file.txt` fits the memory.